# mysql quote of the day query: cope with missing id's

Tags: mysql

I managed to create the following "quote of the day" script. Check www.kakivi.de where you can see on the bottom to the right "kindersprüche".
The present query is running fine as long as all the id's are consecutive. When one or more id's are missing (because the records have been deleted), the script obviously will nor return a quote for a specific id that is not there. Question: how can I make the belowmentioned script tö "skip" id's that are missing? Thanks for your tips and suggestions in advance.

```
SELECT id, spruch, vorname, nachname, datum_eintrag FROM kindersprueche 
WHERE id=`datediff`(CURDATE(),'2015-02-22') MOD (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM kindersprueche)
```

Comment: Are you using PHP to make the database call and render the data? You could use PHP to check the output & run another query when necessary.

Comment: Can you explain more on how you retrieve a quote? Do you query for a certain id?

Comment: yep, I query for an id. But when that id is not present in the table, because the related quote has already been deleted, no quote will be shown. So for example: the present ID's are: 1,2, 6,7,8 and so on.
In the present script, when ID = 3,4 or 5, no quote will be shown. I would like the script to pick ID=6 after ID =2 instead of ID=3.

By the way: I will keep Kitty's suggestion in mind. However, would be great to solve this straight forward with a "first time right" query ;-)

Comment: WHERE something >= something else ORDER BY something LIMIT 1;

Comment: oeps, Strawberry. Your tip is too "short" for me. How do I integrate your suggestion in the abovementioned script?

Comment: Come on, have a stab at it.

Comment: @Strawberry your solution is good... post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT id, spruch, vorname, nachname, datum_eintrag
FROM kindersprueche CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM kindersprueche) n
WHERE id >= datediff(CURDATE(), '2015-02-22') MOD (maxid + 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that I changed the condition to use `MAX(id)` rather than `COUNT(*)`.  I also moved it into the `FROM` clause, so it is easier to read the query.

EDIT:

I think the way to fix this is to add a sequential column to your quotes.  You can do this in the query as:

```
SELECT id, spruch, vorname, nachname, datum_eintrag
FROM (select k.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from kindersprueche cross join (select @rn := 0) params
     ) k CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM kindersprueche) n
WHERE id >= datediff(CURDATE(), '2015-02-22') MOD (cnt + 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Other ways to solve this:

- Add a column that is sequential (perhaps auto-incremented) into the table and set it so there are no gaps.
- Use `offset` along with `limit` to get the values.  However, you need to set this up in the application layer, rather than just in the query.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, your query runs fabulous !!! On behalf of all the children from St.Vinzenz KInderhaus (www.kakivi.de): thank you very much !!!

Comment: i was a bit too early with the conclusion that everything runs fine. The problem is partially solved now. At least for every ID, there will be shown a quote, which is far better than just showing nothing. 

However, for missing ID's, the script jumps to the first present ID and shows the related quote. Means that if 4 ID's are missing (where every ID represents a day), the script will show for those missing ID's the same quote. In practice: During four days you will see the quote of the fourth day (ID1, ID2, ID3 and ID4 will all show the quote of ID5). Any ideas how to solve this?